# multiple select field pass ajax data as string

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

My problem is the quantity value pass as a string not as an array. like `["1,2"]`, however what I need is `[1,2]`

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Quantity:</label>
    <select name="quantity[]" id="quantity" class="form-control" multiple>
    </select>
  </div>
```

```js
// get the quantity value:
if (res) {
  $("#quantity").empty();
  $.each(res, function(key, value) {
    $("#quantity").append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
  });
} else {
  $("#quantity").empty();
}

// pass the quantity value:
var quantity = new Array(); //storing the selected values inside an array
$('#quantity :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
  quantity[i] = $(selected).val();
});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "{{route('localBook.store')}}?quantity[]=" + quantity,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: form_data,
  success: function(res) {}
});
```

Comment: why send it in the url instead in the data field? that will be easier

Comment: b/c i want pass object "form_data". if t do data:{quanity:quanity, form_data} the object become string (1 line  like name=&type_of_organization=&city_id=&type=Room&start);

Comment: this happens because you just putted the `form_data` into data-field, but forgot to define an identifier `identifier: variable` => `form_data: form_data`

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you are passing the quantity-array as a url parameter instead of passing it in the http body (as intended in the post request). This is redundant if you want to perform a POST-request.

Edit your request, pass data through the data-field in your ajax request and everything will work fine. :)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "{{route('localBook.store')}}",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    quantity: this.quantity
  },
  success: function(res) {}
});
```

Cheers,

Niklas

Comment: thanks, Niklas for fast response quantity works fine, but i use url, to pass form_data in data. when i use data:{form_data, quantity:quantity}.  form_quantity vaue in single line. how to overcame this problem

Comment: Now :
form_data:"name=&type_of_organization=&city_id=&type=Room&start_price=300+ETB+-+&end_price=10000….
Before:
name: null, type_of_organization: null, city_id: "68", type: "Room",

how to change to object

Comment: You can pass multiple values through the request (data-field), like: `data { quantity: this quantity, form_data: form_data },`